# How to add SVG <text> in Blazor/razor file

Tags: blazor, razor-pages

I have a Blazor app (.Net 3.1 Core) that generate an SVG image. It is generated like any other HTML using razor/Blazor syntax. The problem is when generating SVG `<text>` elements. I have tried

```
<text x="0">Some text</text>
```

and this results in invalid syntax since  is special in razor files. I have also tried

```
@:<text x="0">Some text</text>
```

which is accepted by razor, but this results in tags getting removed and attributes rendered as normal text instead of SVG tags.

How do I write an SVG `<text>` element in razor syntax? I don't want to revert to C# and HtmlString etc.

Update: Missing key point here was that I used it inside a @foreach, which I first didn't think was relevant.

Comment: What is your exact error? For wich exact svg code?  Because basically this just works.

Comment: I'm not at the computer right now, but I just found this and my issue is also in a foreach. https://forums.asp.net/t/1988241.aspx?SVG+text+tag+in+foreach+loop

Answer (score 8):

Wrapping the SVG `<text>` in a razor `<text>` like below works, but it ain't pretty or intuitive :)

```
<text>
<text x="0">Some text</text>
</text>
```

I'm not sure why @: didn't work as I understood it `@:stuff` and `<text>stuff</text>` should be equivalent.

Comment: There is [an issue](https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/issues/11612) about `@:` , basically the workaround has its own problems.